# How to add new checkbox in chatter Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I have new boolean field in mail.thread model and I want to propagate vice-versa with chatter. I mean I want to add new checkbox field that will reflect the value of my boolean field and when we edit this checkbox in chatter view, I want to reflect this change to my boolean field. Actually I want to use this boolean field when send an email. I am working on odoo16. Thanks for any reference.
[image]